# Is there a Dropdown on extend event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, events, dropdown

I want to run a function that is always triggered when I open a certain Dropdown(Select). The first thing I tried was an onclick event in the select tag, but the problem is that the function is also triggered when I click any option inside the Dropdown.

The function should go through all input fields with a certain class-Name and take their values to build the options of the dropdown, which is working all right. The thing is, i can't choose one of the options as the fillDropdownReq()-function is always triggered after i try to choose something.

Is there any way to just trigger the event when i open the dropdown?

```js
function fillDropdownReq(DD){
    let dropdown = $('#'+DD.id);

    dropdown.empty();

    dropdown.append('<option disabled>choose Prerequisite</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    $(".fieldName_checkbox").each(function (){
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', $(this).val()).text($(this).val()));
    })
}
```

```css
.fieldName_checkbox{
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.select_div{
  float: right;
  margin: 25px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="fieldName_checkbox" id="fieldName_checkbox1" value="testvalue1">
<input class="fieldName_checkbox" id="fieldName_checkbox2" value="testvalue2">

<div class="select_div">
<select id="fieldPrerequisitesSelect" onclick="fillDropdownReq(this)">
  <option selected="true" disabled>choose Prerequisite</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'extended' or 'opened' event available for `select` elements.

One workaround for this case would be to invert your logic; populate the `option` elements in the `select` whenever the user interacts with any of the `input` fields used to create their values, something like this:

```js
let $select = $('#fieldPrerequisitesSelect');
let updateOptions = () => {
  let options = $fields.map((i, el) => `<option value="${el.value}">${el.value}</option>`).get();
  options.unshift('<option selected="true" disabled>choose Prerequisite</option>');
  $select.html(options);
}

let $fields = $('.fieldName_checkbox').on('input', updateOptions);
updateOptions();
```

```css
.fieldName_checkbox {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.select_div {
  float: right;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="fieldName_checkbox" id="fieldName_checkbox1" value="testvalue1" />
<input class="fieldName_checkbox" id="fieldName_checkbox2" value="testvalue2" />

<div class="select_div">
  <select id="fieldPrerequisitesSelect">
    <option selected="true" disabled>choose Prerequisite</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

*Update...*

Based on your comment under the question:

> I would have to do that... when a new 'select' element is created fill that with options as well

Then you can just use `clone()` to create a new `select` as required, and convert the `id` to a `class` so that you can update the options within all `select` elements at the same time. The code for that would look like this:

```js
let updateOptions = () => {
  let options = $fields.map((i, el) => `<option value="${el.value}">${el.value}</option>`).get();
  options.unshift('<option selected="true" disabled>choose Prerequisite</option>');
  $('.fieldPrerequisitesSelect').html(options);
}

let $fields = $('.fieldName_checkbox').on('input', updateOptions);
updateOptions();

$('.duplicate-select').on('click', e => {
  let $clone = $('.select_div:first').clone().insertAfter('.select_div:last');
  $clone.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```css
input,
button,
.select_div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="fieldName_checkbox" id="fieldName_checkbox1" value="testvalue1" /><br />
<input class="fieldName_checkbox" id="fieldName_checkbox2" value="testvalue2" /><br />

<button type="button" class="duplicate-select">Duplicate select</button>

<div class="select_div">
  <select class="fieldPrerequisitesSelect">
    <option selected="true" disabled>choose Prerequisite</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah i thought of that, too, but the user can add 'select' and 'input' elements dynamically, so i would have to do that, what you suggested there and always, when a new 'select' element is created fill that with options as well, so i would have preferred to just get what i need for a 'select' when this 'select' gets extended. But there is just no way to do that, i guess.. Thank you for help